# Why is my MVC viewModel null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to pass a viewModel to an edit form view. The issue is that I instanciate the model and assign values to it, but the model remains null.

My Action:

```
    public ActionResult OrderEdit(takeOrder FormInput)
    {
        takeOrder viewModel = new takeOrder
        {
            Name= "anonymous",
            TableNumber = 13,
            FoodItems = new List<FoodItem> {
                new FoodItem{ DishName = "Dishname value 1", Price = 10 },
                new FoodItem{ DishName = "Dishname value 2", Price = 20 },
                new FoodItem{ DishName = "Dishname value 3", Price = 30 },
                new FoodItem{ DishName = "Dishname value 4", Price = 40 },
            }
        };
        if (FormInput != null)
            viewModel = FormInput;

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

And my view looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/genesis.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Genesis_0_02.Models.takeOrder>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    OrderEdit
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <h2>OrderEdit</h2>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
        <p>
            <%: Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name) %><br />
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%: Html.LabelFor(x => x.TableNumber) %><br />
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TableNumber) %>
        </p>
        <button type="button" id="AddListItem">Add a dish to your order</button>
        <br />
        <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.FoodItems.Count(); i++ )%>
        <% { %>
        <div class="ListItem">
        <button type="button" class="RemoveListItem">X</button>
            Dish: <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FoodItems[i].DishName, new { style = "width:60px;" } )%>
            Price: <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FoodItems[i].Price, new { style = "width:60px;" })%>
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <br />
<button type="submit">Submit Order</button>

    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Source Error: 


Line 64:         <button type="button" id="AddListItem">Add a dish to your order</button>
Line 65:         <br />
--> error --> Line 66:         <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.FoodItems.Count(); i++ )%>
Line 67:         <% { %>
Line 68:         <div class="ListItem">


Source File: pathtotheproject\Genesis.0.02\Genesis.0.02\Views\Admin\OrderEdit.aspx    Line: 66
```

I added a breakpoint on `viewModel` in my Action `OrderEdit` and all of the values were being passed as null to the view. I don't understand this because I hardcoded values for every parameter.

Why is my `viewModel` null?

#### edit

I do have javascript that adds dishes to the form. I took that out of the view listed above because it isn't relevent to the error.

#### edit: response to @Loki Stormbringer's answer

The `FormInput` paramter in `public ActionResult OrderEdit(takeOrder FormInput)` is intended to be bound to a formpost.

When I comment out:

```
        // if (FormInput != null)
        //    viewModel = FormInput;
```

Then the code performs as expected. But I don't understand why a `null` object is being assigned when I am specifically checking that the object is not null. The intended behavior is that if a form has been submitted then the `viewModel` is assigned the edited values, and if there is no form post submission then the `viewModel` uses the default values. Eventually, those default values will be coming from a db.

Why does `if (FormInput != null)` return true when `FormInput` is null?

Comment: I couldn't advocate more strongly for you to change your coding style.  It is literally the exact opposite of the standard style with camel-cased class names and upper-case parameter names.  (It should be the other way around)

Comment: Speaking to the error itself, you do hard-code every parameter, but then you proceed to overwrite that work with `if (FormInput != null) viewModel = FormInput;`.  Presumably `FormInput` is not null, but all the properties inside are null.  Is this the result of a postback?  Why would you expect `FormInput` to have valid data?

Comment: @Kirk Woll - I was unaware that there was such a convention.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx, and particularly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: @Kirk Woll - thank you for the the resource! I'm gonna have to develop some new habits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this has been noticed, but your Model is *not* actually null according to that error; `ArgumentNullException`. It would be `NullReferenceException` if Model was null

`ArgumentNullException` means that the `Model.FoodItems` collection is null when being passed to the `Count()` Extension method.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of the FormInput parameter?  How are you calling this Action?  My guess is that FormInput has something in it and is not null so the line

if (FormInput != null) 
        viewModel = FormInput;

is executed which then blows away anything you put in viewModel above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I commented out the if statement and it worked as expected. But, this doesn't make sense to me because `viewModel = FormInput` should only be assigned if `FormInput` is NOT null. So somehow the if statement says `FormInput` is not null but the assignment thinks that `FormInput` is null. I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

You have below in your Page header... is your viewmodel class definitely named "takeOrder"

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Genesis_0_02.Models.takeOrder>
```

**Edit**
I just reread your post and it is your Model name... first thing would be to rename to TakeOrder

Comment: Thanks Matt, @Kirk Woll also pointed out my lack of convention when naming objects and parameters.